# Sorting nested lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list

```
list_a = 
[['1 order', 15, 3 ],
['1 order', 29, 2],
['1 order', 5, 1],
['2 order', 2, 3],
['2 order', 1, 2],
['2 order', 17, 1],
['3 order', 2, 3],
['3 order', 10, 2],
['3 order', 1, 1]]
```

After applying sorting on second element

```
sort_by_second_attribute = sorted(list_a, key = lambda k : k[1])
```

output is

```
[['2 order', 1, 2],
['3 order', 1, 1],
['2 order', 2, 3],
['3 order', 2, 3],
['1 order', 5, 1],
['3 order', 10, 2],
['1 order', 15, 3],
['2 order', 17, 1],
['1 order', 29, 2]]
```

But, I want to maintain the sorted order of first attribute and then sort on second attribute. The output I want is

```
[['1 order', 5, 3],
['1 order', 15, 2],
['1 order', 29, 1],
['2 order', 1, 3],
['2 order', 2, 2],
['2 order', 17, 1],
['3 order', 1, 3],
['3 order', 2, 2],
['3 order', 10, 1]]
```

Comment: What you're asking is (almost) default sort mechanism: `sorted_list = sorted(list_a)`.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
sort_by_second_attribute = sorted(list_a, key = lambda k : (k[0], k[1]))
```

But ideally don't store your data in lists, but create appropriate objects for it. Because it's totally unclear from your code what index=1 or index=2 mean, what data is stored under those indexes.

Comment: this raises a syntaxerror, see the other answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use a secondary sorting condition by making a tuple

```
list_b = sorted(list_a, key=lambda k: (k[0], k[1]))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 helping.py 
> [['1 order', 5, 1], ['1 order', 15, 3], ['1 order', 29, 2], ['2 
> order', 1, 2], ['2 order', 2, 3], ['2 order', 17, 1], ['3 order', 1,
> 1], ['3 order', 2, 3], ['3 order', 10, 2]]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a tuple from your `key`, eg`key = lambda k : (k[1], k[2])`, and the attributes are sorted in that order.